# Can I hook up Three monitors to my inspiron 3847?

Tags: windows-8

I have the dell inspiron 3847 and i want to hook up Three 21.5 inch asus monitors to it. I play PC games on it and want a wider view. Not the same image on each screen. Is it possible? If so how. Thanks!

Comment: What graphics card do you have? It's possible, but depends a lot on the specs of your system. Try using a program such as speccy (https://www.piriform.com/speccy) to find out and then [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/933387/edit) your question.

Comment: I have one vga and an hdm1

Comment: Then you cannot currently drive 3 monitors without buying a new graphics card. You will need to buy one with a minimum of 3 outputs. Depending on your games and the monitor resolutions 3 screens is very demanding so you may well want to get a high end card, as you have a generic Dell system your power supply might also need to be upgraded at the  same time.

Comment: I cant get a usb to a vga adapter?? Or even a spliter?

Comment: USB to VGA adaptors are a stopgap to get you a display, all the reviews I've seen state that their performance is, at best, utter garbage and that's just for 2d tasks. They are not meant for gaming and have no 3d acceleration. Splitters only work if you want the same picture on all three monitors, again this is not what you want. I refer you to my previous comment suggesting a new graphics card.

Comment: And around what price would the one i need be??

Comment: I am kind of on a budget

Comment: I just looked up a graphic card and its 54 dollars. It has a VGA, DVI, and HDMI. That will work correct? I Just will need to get a good HDMI to VGA/DVI for one of them right?

Comment: So long as all three monitors accept either VGA or DVI in, then yes, that should just about work.  If possible I would recommend getting monitors that have both DVI and VGA in as there are caveats that could cause problems otherwise, you can convert HDMI to DVI, but not HDMI to VGA, but you *should* be able to convert the DVI **on the graphics card** to VGA. At $54 I wouldn't expect it to perform spectacularly, but it could be passable if you turn the quality down a bit in the games.  Out of curiosity, what monitors are they?

Comment: They are Asus VS228 monitors. They have VGA, DVI, and HDMI. So i will be good with the Graphic card that has thoes three right? Just need the hdmi to DV1? And i can get different display on all of them? Or widen the view?

Comment: I would recommend searching for your graphics card model and "triple monitor" on Google, some graphics cards have 3 outputs but can only use 2 displays on them at once...If you can, you need to find a card that has two outputs (HDMI or DVI or VGA) which you connect to your monitors and also a DisplayPort output for the third monitor, then you get a DisplayPort to HDMI or DVI adaptor.  That is almost guaranteed to work.  Otherwise [this card](http://www.amazon.com/dp/B006GTDSC6) claims to support 3 monitors out of the box...  you'd be better off buying a card that states triple monitor support.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to buy a graphics card that has three outputs on it.  The problem is though that not all graphics cards are created equal and there is a lot of cards out there that have three outputs yet can only drive two of those outputs at once.

What this means is that you have two options:

- to either buy a graphics card with two "normal" outputs (HDMI, DVI or VGA) as well as a DisplayPort output, and then buy a DisplayPort to HDMI/DVI/VGA adaptor as well.  If you have a particularly low budget this is going to difficult as [Displayport adaptors](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005H3I38Q) are easily $10 - $15 on their own.
- to buy a graphics card that claims to support driving all three outputs at once such as [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B006GTDSC6)

Once you have the card and monitors hooked up and the drivers installed you should simply be able to go into the control pane for the graphics card and set them up as fully independent displays.  Depending on whether you bought ATI or Nvidia their settings will be slightly different but they will both be able to use them as either separate displays or to "span" a single desktop across all three, resulting in one long desktop.

Comment: Is the graphics  card you sent me one that can actually DISPLAY 3 at a time? Or do I have to go even bigger. (Money)

Comment: @DianeMangiavillano The graphics card I linked (http://www.amazon.com/dp/B006GTDSC6/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) claims to do 3 displays "out of the box" on it's packaging (underneath the "1GB DDR3" writing) so all you need to do is connect 2 displays via DVI and the 3rd via HDMI.  You could even connect all 3 via DVI using the HDMI to DVI cable that looks to be included.  It might not have great performance on the latest games though, so you might have to turn quality down a bit in games when running all 3 displays.  Other than that, it should "just work".

Comment: Ok. Thank you soo much for all the advice and help. I really appreciaye it!  I have another question if you dont mind

Comment: @DianeMangiavillano Sure, what's the question?

Comment: I've been a console gamer for my whole life I've had my desktop for about a year but never really used it. I don't know anything about desktops and i was just wondering for the future when I eventually do upgrade to everything is there any type of computer that is very very

Comment: Is there any type of computer that I don't have to worry about anything and I can upgrade it as much

Comment: What im trying to ask is there any computer out there that has all the tools and gadgets that make it efforless to do thing like connect 3 monitors and it will run flawlessly?

Comment: @DianeMangiavillano Not really, no.  All the parts that make up computers are constantly evolving and what is hard today could be easy tomorrow and features come and go.  I like both consoles and computer, consoles are good for consistency and knowing that whatever game you buy for it will just work, computers can adapt faster to new trends and are generally more powerful but have too much configurability for it to always do what everyone wants, hence why there are so many quirks and caveats.  Sadly there's always going to be a learning curve to figure out if it'll do exactly what you want.

Comment: I just picked up R9-270X is that good?

Comment: It is a very good card, but I don't know much about that series.  Some things online suggest that you *should* be able to run 3 monitors without problems, and that card should be able to handle most games.  Make sure it's all plugged in properly and that your power supply can handle the extra load, otherwise have fun!

Comment: Hello. Its me again haha, after some time thinking. I am just going to buy a new gaming desktop. And it has a gtx 960 graphics card in it. The graphic card claims to be able to run most games at 1080P.. but then I see all these comments and reviews and some say its garbadge and it cant run 3 monitors. Can it??? I would use a wide display on the 3 monitors and i would only be playing csgo, H1Z1, and World at War zombies. So can that card support 3 monitors and run fine at 1080P?

Comment: @DianeMangiavillano Heya. A dedicated new machine designed for gaming is often the safest way to go. The [GTX 960 specs](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-960/specifications) page states it can drive 4 displays, but I suspect that two of those displays have to be via the DisplayPort ports, which means you would need DisplayPort adaptors: http://www.amazon.com/dp/B005H3I38Q/?tag=stackoverfl08-20  Make sure the graphics card in the machine has an HDMI port, a DVI port and at least one DisplayPort and then with one of those adaptors I think you should be fine.

Comment: This is the oneim going to buy. Will it work?

Comment: http://m.newegg.com/Product/index?itemnumber=83-227-602

Comment: @DianeMangiavillano it claims "1 VGA, 1 DVI, 1 HDMI, 1 Display port" so I think it should work so long as you get the adaptor I mentioned. A lot of graphics cards can only drive two of the three "Standard" ports (VGA, HDMI, DVI) at once and require displays number 3 and 4 to be driven off of DisplayPort sockets. VGA is rubbish so get the adaptor and use the DVI as well as HDMI and a DisplayPort to HDMI adaptor. As far as I know that *should* work.

Comment: So just get the adaptors and i can run my wide display on 1080P?

Comment: Oh by the way I remembered that all the monitors come with adaptors

Comment: You should only need one DisplayPort adaptor. Other than that as far as I am aware it should just work.